# Problem in receiving messages using @JmsListener with ActiveMQ Artemis when send using topic name as String in convertAndSend method

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis, jms-topic

I am sending to an ActiveMQ Artemis topic. The topic is created using the following code:

```java
@Bean
public ActiveMQTopic sampleTopic(){
    return new org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQTopic("topicName");
}
```

If I send the message to a topic using the `convertAndSend` with `sampleTopic` as argument I receive the message in the listener.

```java
@Autowired
private Topic sampleTopic;

jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(sampleTopic, jsonMessage, m -> {
    m.setStringProperty("type", "new");
    m.setStringProperty("sender", "abc");

    return m;
});
```

But if I send the message using the `String` name of topic as an argument to the `convertAndSend()` the message is not received by the listener.

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("topicName", jsonMessage, m -> {
    m.setStringProperty("type", "new");
    m.setStringProperty("sender", "abc");

    return m;
});
```

The `@JmsListener` looks like this:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "topicName",
             containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",
             subscription = "new",
             selector = "type = 'new' and sender = 'abc'")
@Transactional
public void onMessage(String payload) {
    
}
```

Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@Profile("local")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-local.properties")
public class MessagingConfigArtemis {

    private static final String ARTEMIS_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    private static final String ARTEMIS_USERNAME = "artemis";
    private static final String ARTEMIS_PASSWORD = "artemis";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(ARTEMIS_BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setUser(ARTEMIS_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(ARTEMIS_PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(jmsConnectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory returnValue = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        returnValue.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return returnValue;
    }


    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> topicJmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory returnValue = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        returnValue.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        returnValue.setSubscriptionShared(true);
        returnValue.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        returnValue.setPubSubDomain(Boolean.TRUE);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

As per my understanding the listener should be able to recieve the message from the topic, for both type of `convertAndSend()` methods (i.e. one with `String` and other with `Topic` as argument). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot creates a `JmsTemplate` configured to [transmit to queues](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/jms/sending.html) by having `pubSubDomain` set to `false`. The `JmsMessageListenerContainer` is also configured the same way. To override and publish to topics, set `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true` through Spring Boot’s property settings (either inside `application.properties` or by setting an environment variable).

Comment: The PubSubDomain to True in the configuration. in  the JmsTopicJmsListenerContainerFactory

Comment: Added the configuration

Comment: The problem is that you are **not** calling `jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true)` in your `jmsTemplate()` method. Therefore, when you use `jmsTemplate` to _send_ the message it is being sent with JMS queue semantics. You must send _and_ consume with JMS topic semantics (i.e. using pubSubDomain=true).

Comment: What if i have queues and topics?

Comment: You could have jmsTemplate for queues (i.e. queuesJMSTemplate.setPubSubDomain(false)) and a jmsTemplate for topics (i.e. topicsJMSTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true))